# Ansible: How to execute set_fact module from within ansible action plugin python code

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-module

I am writing a custom Action Plugin for Ansible which I use in my playbook and I am trying to set a variable that will be used in the next task, in the playbook, by a (custom) module.

Effectively, the playbook equivalent of what I am trying to mimic is a set_fact task like so:

```yaml
- name: set_fact task
  set_fact: 
    ansible_python_interpreter: /path/to/python
```

In my custom Action Plugin, I have used `self._execute_module` before to execute other modules (such as slurp) within the plugin code. However, with the `set_fact` module it doesn't seem to be updating the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable, as expected.

I have tried the following:

```py
self._execute_module(module_name='ansible.builtin.set_fact',
                     module_args=dict(ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/python),
                     task_vars=task_vars)
```

And I have also tried different variations of `module_args`:

```py
module_args=dict(key_value={ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/python})
```

```
module_args=dict(key_value='ansible_python_interpreter:/path/to/python')
```

However, my `ansible_python_interpreter` does not seem to be changing.

Any help, please?

Comment: `set_fact` is actually an action plugin, itself, this is maybe why this is not working as you expect it. This is backed up by: 1/ the module being an empty Python file, except for its documentation and examples: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/set_fact.py; 1/ the plugin action file: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/set_fact.py

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yeah thats a good caveat I didn't consider initially. I have posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can get is to return a `dict` containing the Ansible facts that I want to be set for the playbook simply by following the dev guide for Action Plugins on the Ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#action-plugins).

So, as I am returning an `_execute_model()` call in my plugin as well, my `run()` function in my plugin would look something like this:

```
def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
    # Plugin code here

    facts = dict()
    facts['ansible_python_interpreter'] = '/path/to/python'

    return dict(self._execute_module(module_name='my_custom_module',
                                     module_args=module_args,
                                     task_vars=task_vars),
                ansible_facts=dict(facts))
```

However, unfortunately this throws another warning/error of:

`[WARNING]: Removed restricted key from module data: ansible_python_interpreter`

And this seems to be due to a [safety mechanism for overriding connection details](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37535#issuecomment-373820351), and so I have gone down a different route for my plugin.

In another use case, returning `dict(ansible_facts=dict(facts))` (like in the docs) would work if it wasn't a connection var I was trying to override, I believe.